# How to bundle html, js and css in one html file with webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpagetest

I have built my application with **webpack** merging all css into one file, all js into one file and having one html for my SPA app.

When I do my testing with webpagetest most of my issues is not with loading the files but loading them as individual files.

`html+css+js=index.html`

How do I pack my html, css and js into a single index.html, so I **can avoid http overhead**?

Webpack or any webpack plugin is better, since we are already using it.

Thanks for any direction on this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I use [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) inject the output from Webpack into a index.html file.

Assuming you mean you want to inline all those files into one http request of `index.html` you can use [`html-webpack-inline-source-plugin`](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin) to achieve this.

Comment: Newbie question here, why do I need to add html to webpack? I thought we were only concerned with css and js optimization to reduce network requests.

Comment: @PirateApp the html-webpack-plugin does a lot more than reduce the size of your entry `index.html` file that loads `.js` & `.css`. It's too much to cover in a comment. But the basic usage of it is to help update the `.html` file with the output from webpack if you hash the outputs e.g `main.1s8h3.css`. This tends to change on every webpack build when you change your source css.

It also supports html template languages and has loads of plugins https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#plugins

Comment: Note: For it to work in Webpack 4, you need to take extra steps: https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin/issues/63#issuecomment-515963062

Comment: The package says that it is no longer maintained and Facebook provides a similar plugin.  I don't find anyone talking about this plugin.

Comment: thats very old and do not work with any new version

Answer (score 13):

shameless plug incoming

I found webpack too heavy weight, especially when I'm already using browserify to inline my `require()`'s. So I wrote a ~30 line npm cli package using JS's `string.replace`:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-scripts.
Usage, `$ inline-scripts src/index.html out/index.html`

Comment: Hello, why your code isn't open sourced please ?

Comment: It is, https://github.com/mahhov/inline-scripts, I simply haven't linked the git repo in the npm package.json