# How to reference css/js bundles in a html page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, bundling-and-minification

I want to reference a css and js bundle in html page defined in my global.asax.cs

Global.asax.cs

```
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(
                new StyleBundle("~/StyleSheets/kendo/css")
                .Include("~/StyleSheets/kendo/kendo.common.min.css")
                .Include("~/StyleSheets/kendo/kendo.default.min.css")
                );



var KendoForJquery = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo_jquery_script")
                .Include("~/_scripts/kendo/jquery.min.js")
                .Include("~/_scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js");
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.Add(KendoForJquery);
```

In MVC Page , i refer bundles like this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/StyleSheets/kendo/css")
```

But i want to refer above two bundles in html, how i can do it ?

Comment: something related found here using webpack >  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866228/how-to-bundle-html-js-and-css-in-one-html-file-with-webpack/46875379#46875379

Comment: I think you meant to have Styles.Render  in your above example of use.  Are you trying to access the stylesheets/scripts from js or something?  What kind of reference are you trying to get?  A reference to the url of the sheet/script?

Comment: I have one html page , i want to reference css and js bundles defined in global.asax.cs